# Drupal 7 FlexSlider - pictures not in center position

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, drupal-7, flexslider

I have a following problem with a Flexslider module in Drupal 7. I've made a simple slider which displays 3 photos. I've turned on slider for touch screen and everething works fine apart from the fact that all the photos are moved to the right so that you can see the snippet of the previous photo. It is about 15 pixels, but it is very annoying and looks just bad. I've already tried to change something in the **flexslider.css** file, but it still doesn't work properly. Do you know how to fix it?

[image: How does the slider look (notice the snippet on the left side)]

Comment: Do you have a link for us? Or is your site local? I think the problem is the width of the Flexslider, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Appel Unfortunetaly I develeop the website locally, but I've added a screenshot which shows what my problem is. I use AT Subtheme as an initial theme for my website.

Comment: Use something like Firebug. Maybe there is a padding, margin or something that is overruling your CSS settings. I think that is the issue. You can also look to your Flexslider width and your image width. Maybe your image is to small?

Comment: The image is not too small. I've checked it and the problem is that in the 'neutral position' the piture is moved these 15 pixels to the right. But when the slider is located in another region in Drupal, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove a few lines from my theme's .css and now it works fine.

Comment: what lines did you have to remove to fix this? I have the same issue. Mainly on page load. When you first see the Flexslider load it is off a little and if you resize the page it snaps into place. Can't find a solution for this behavior

Comment: @tjoenz Unfortunately I don't remember and because of various reasons I don't  have access to this project anymore, so I can't tell you :(.

Comment: that is ok. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied padding or margins to any elements? Applying a margin to the container of flexslider (I think its flex-viewport) will shift it.

Comment: The situation presented on the screenshot occurs when no changes are made to the .css of the flexslider. Of course I tried to change margins and padding of fleexslider, but it was even worse.

Comment: Ok, I can't really tell too much from the screenshot. Do you have a link to your site that I could look at?